# XSD <element><complexType><sequence> vs. <element><sequence>

Tags: xml, xsd

I'd like to have something like:

```
<element>
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      ...
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

Do I really need the complexType level?
Or would it be enough to have:

```
<element>
  <sequence>
    ...
  </sequence>
</element>
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to repeat the use of the complexType, such as:

```
<element> 
  <complexType> 
    <sequence> 
      ... 
    </sequence> 
  </complexType> 
  <complexType> 
    <sequence> 
      ... 
    </sequence> 
  </complexType> 
</element>
```

Then yes, you need the complextype

Comment: And if I'm not? I want the outer element only to contain one sequence.

Comment: no, you either need the simpletype or the complex type in your xsd - they wont appear in your xml though?

Comment: sequence cannot be a child node of element